# How can I stop boxplot from shifting right when I use geom_text?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am creating a single `boxplot` using `ggplot`, and everything is fine until I use `geom_text` to add label to horizontal line.

This is the code I am using without `geom_text` and the corresponding output:

```
ggplot(data = x_frame, aes(x = '', y = x_frame)) +
  scale_y_log10(labels = comma, name='Transaction (GBP)') +
  geom_boxplot() +
  ggtitle('Box & Whisker')+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = SE, colour = 'Tukey'), linetype='dashed') +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean(x),colour = 'Mean'),linetype='dashed') +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean_std,colour = 'Mean & 1Std'),linetype='dashed')+
  scale_colour_manual(name = 'Thresholds', values=c(Tukey='red', Mean='blue', 'Mean & 1Std'='darkred'))+
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = c('Tukey','Mean','Mean & 1Std'), size = 3)))
```

[image: Without<code>geom_text</code>]

And here is the code after using `geom_text` and the output:

```
ggplot(data = x_frame, aes(x = '', y = x_frame)) +
  scale_y_log10(labels = comma, name='Transaction (GBP)') +
  geom_boxplot() +
  ggtitle('Box & Whisker')+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = SE, colour = 'Tukey'), linetype='dashed') +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean(x),colour = 'Mean'),linetype='dashed') +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean_std,colour = 'Mean & 1Std'),linetype='dashed')+
  scale_colour_manual(name = 'Thresholds', values=c(Tukey='red', Mean='blue', 'Mean & 1Std'='darkred'))+
  geom_text(aes(y=SE, label=prettyNum(round(SE),big.mark=","), x=0.1), colour='red', hjust=-0.1 , vjust = 1) +
  geom_text(aes(y=mean(x), label=prettyNum(round(mean(x)),big.mark=","), x=0.1), colour='blue', hjust=-0.1 , vjust = -0.5 ) +
  geom_text(aes(y=mean_std, label=prettyNum(round(mean_std),big.mark=","), x=0.1), colour='darkred', hjust=-0.1 , vjust = -0.5) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = c('Tukey','Mean','Mean & 1Std'), size = 3)))
```

[image: with <code>geom_text</code>]

I am sorry I cannot post the data, but simply it is a vector of numbers with high standard deviation (hence, why I am using the log transformation).

Many thanks

Comment: as far as I can tell both figures posted are the same

Comment: My guess (in addition to Gordon's comment that the pics are identical) is that your `geom_text(...,x=0.1)` should be more like `x=0.5` or more.

Comment: Many thanks, this actually solved the problem. Apologies, I uploaded the same picture twice